# mixpanel: alias not working with python

Tags: mixpanel

Below is my code using python, I receive Null response with no errors, I don't see the alias in effect in my mixpanel login.

```
from mixpanel import Mixpanel
mp = Mixpanel("********project token**********")
mp.alias("NEW_DISTINCT_ID","EXISTING_DISTINCT_ID")
```

Comment: It's actually working, we cannot observe it on the mixpanel login UI, use mp.track("NEW_DISTINCT_ID","Login") to verify if that is mapping.

Answer (score 1):

What you mention is correct because the alias method is not retroactive: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.alias